# break doesn't break while loop. why?

Tags: python

I'm trying to do a login system from text file.
When I enter wrong input that isn't in the text it does what I want it to do, which is to output "wrong username and password" and "try again" and ask for username and pass again.
But when I enter correct details, the loop never breaks. It keeps asking for user and pass.
Here is my code:

```
def check():
        users = open('student.txt').read().split('\n')
        for i in range(len(users)): users[i] = users[i].split(',')


        while True:
            username = str(input('Username: '))
            password = str(input('Password: '))

            for user in users:
                uname = user[3]
                pword = user[4]

                if uname == username and pword == password:
                    print('Hello ' + user[0] + '.')
                    print('You are logged in as: ' + user[3] +  '.')
                    break
                
                    

            else:
                print('Wrong username/password.')
                print('Try again!\n\n')
    check()
```

Comment: what does `student.txt` file contain? Do you know if the values of `user[3]` and `user[4]` are userid and passwords? Also, are you reading all the records in the file. I see only one read() statement. That may read only one line

Comment: Your `break` statement is within a `for` loop that's within a `while` loop. That's your issue.

Comment: yes values is userid and pass and it reads all records

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using a `break` statement, it will only exit the inner loop it is currently in, which means it will still be looping the outer loop. The common approach for this problem would be to refractor your nested loop into a function and use a `return` statement to exit the code.

Another approach would be adding some `continue` statement to avoid reaching a second `break` and only reach it when the inner loop is exited. Something like this:

```
def check():
      users = open('student.txt').read().split('\n')
       for i in range(len(users)):
            users[i] = users[i].split(',')

        while True:
            username = str(input('Username: '))
            password = str(input('Password: '))

            for user in users:
                uname = user[3]
                pword = user[4]

                if uname == username and pword == password:
                    print('Hello ' + user[0] + '.')
                    print('You are logged in as: ' + user[3] + '.')
                    break
            else:
                print('Wrong username/password.')
                print('Try again!\n\n')
                
                # Continue if the inner loop wasn't broken.
                continue

            # Inner loop was broken, break the outer.
            break
```

Comment: thank you for your help you saved me. i have one more question if want to add a small menu when user and pass are correct which break do i replace for the menu?

Comment: Judging from your code, if it is when user and pass are correct it should go within the `if uname == username and pword == password:` condition, so your menu code should go before that break.

Comment: TheBeast, if you have another question please create a new question-post to ask it.

Answer (score 1):

The `break` always leaves the immediate loop construct, the "innermost".
For your code that is the `for` loop, not the `while` loop which contains it.

Answer (score 0):

the `break` statement will break out of `while` AND `for` loops. As frustrating as it might seem, these break statements will only break out of the closest loop. If you take a look at your code, you can see that your break statement is actually called inside of a `for loop` within your `while loop`. This means you are breaking out of the `for loop` but the `while loop` will continue on as normal.

One great alternative to deal with this issue is to turn your while loop into a function and replace your `break` statement with a `return` statement. This way your while loop will also stop!

Answer (score 0):

As said in my comment, your `break` statement is within a `for` loop that's within a `while` loop. `break` statements won't break any outer loops.

Here is a possible solution

```py
def check():
        users = open('student.txt').read().split('\n')
        for i in range(len(users)): users[i] = users[i].split(',')

        username = str(input('Username: '))
        password = str(input('Password: '))

        for user in users:
            uname = user[3]
            pword = user[4]

             while True:

                if uname == username and pword == password:
                    print('Hello ' + user[0] + '.')
                    print('You are logged in as: ' + user[3] +  '.')
                    break
            
                else:
                    print('Wrong username/password.')
                    print('Try again!\n\n')

check()
```