# Python: Can't break out of this while loop

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop

```
    while True:
        result = random.randint(1, 100)
        
        for i in range(len(my_names)):
            my_name = my_names[i]
            my_rd = my_round(my_name, mys_hands[i], result)
            if my_rd == False:
                break
            else:
                for i in range(len(my_names)):
                    if not mys_hands[i]:
                        print("OK!")
                        break
```

Help. I can't seem to break out of this while loop totally without changing anything else in my program (right now my program just restarts at the top of the while loop.

I understand that it's because the last break only breaks out of the for loop and not the while loop. I tried moving the last "break" under various indentations backwards but it breaks my program. I also tried using continue and break as taught [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65747924/break-doesnt-break-while-loop-why#:%7E:text=This%20means%20you%20are%20breaking,while%20loop%20will%20also%20stop!) but it still doesn't work (my program changed). How do I break out of the loop without using a function? Thanks!

Comment: It's not clear which break should do what. Should both `break`s exit the `while` loop or only the first one? Maybe instead of `while True`, you could loop while some state exists and change that state before breaking.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `while True`, use a flag variable, and set that flag variable to false when you break out of the inner loops.

```
flag = True
while flag:
    ...
    for x in something:
        ...
        if want_to_break_out_of_while_loop:
            flag = False
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put this loop in a function and return from a function.

Ergonomic even with deeply nested for loops, but offers less flexibility in choosing which loop to break compared to other answers.

As always - depends on what you want to achieve.

```py
def func():
  while True:
    for i in something:
      for x in something_else:
        return
```